# Set python version on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, mac, python, versions

does someone had situation when "python --version" says "Python 2.7.16", but installed version is 3.7

Command "pyenv versions" says "* 3.7.11 (set by /Users/dima/.python-version)"

My applications see also just version "2.7.16".

Does someone know how to set default Python version to installed "3.7.11"? Simply set entire system default python to 3.7.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please [edit] with details of how you installed Python. Seems like some step has been missed to add the Python you installed to your PATH before the system Python installation.

Comment: `python` is version 2, `python3` is version 3. What exactly do you mean by "Simply set entire system default python to 3.7", and what should happen to python scripts incompatible with version 3? Also, are you just relying on the python binaries which are part of macOS or did you install things yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is python 2, for legacy applications. To use python 3, you must use the command python3. So python3 —-version should be what you are looking for.

Edit: I missed that you're using pyenv. Maybe it's a bug with pyenv, but python3 should still bring python 3.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I don't need pyenv, this is just to check. I using one program, which call python automatically, i cannot decompile it. It's SAP MDK Installer, it calls simply python command. I need to set it somehow globally, but still didn't found how. After restart it's come back to version 2.7.. strange.. cannot find why..

Comment: Then symlink from python3 to python should work. But remember to remove the symlink afterword so it doesn’t interfere with legacy programs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Python installation appears in your PATH before the system Python.

Edit `~/.bash_profile` or the profile file for the shell you're using and add

```
export PATH=/path/to/your/python/bin/folder:$PATH
```

with the path to the folder containing your `python`.

Comment: that won’t work, he needs to use the python3 command to access python. Python2, which is represented by python, is already executing, meaning it’s already in $PATH

Comment: @anon It’s impossible to say at this stage that this won’t work. Depending on how it’s installed (which is why I asked OP to edit), it’s reasonable for the new Python install to add a symlink from `python` to `python3` in its bin folder. Adding the new bin to the *beginning* of the PATH as shown in this answer will cause Python 3 to run with `python` in such installs.